# Easy Problem Bur don't find solution ERC20 contract

Tags: tokens, erc-20

i have a contract that compile well [image]

But the problem remain on how i can generate supply. because i've  generate the contract but no tokens are affected to this and i have no token on my metamask

https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xF699d9d0F716D62891F702F2Acc8e62001207c6d

and i have no token transfered on my metamask bsctestnet

can you explain me why please ? thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ethereum StackExchange! As for the problem, it's hard to know since you're not showing the part which assigns the initial tokens. I suggest you remove code from the contract and try to deploy only a minimal version. when you have that working, you can slowly increase code there

Comment: Thanks for replying in fact i already share my code : https://github.com/Bobigny/OneLife/new/main